# SVG font rendered offset

Tags: svg, matlab

I'm generating figures in MATLAB (MWE below), loading them into LaTeX (Overleaf), and then making them very small.

Is there something I can/should be doing to control the text anchoring such that the text stays where I think it should be (outside the axes in the example below)? Either in MATLAB or LaTeX?

MATLAB (R2023a):

```
x = rand(1,100);
y = rand(1,100);

plot(x,y)

saveas(gcf,'test.svg')
```

[image]

LaTeX (Overleaf, pdfLaTeX, Tex Live: 2022)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{svg}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \includesvg[pretex=\tiny, width=0.3\textwidth]{test.svg}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

*I wasn't sure whether to post this in a MATLAB forum instead, please do let me know if you think this is a MATLAB-specific issue and I can take it down from here*

Comment: Why svg? would be  simpler to make pdf then scale to whatever size is needed

Comment: Because I'm compiling multiple panels using subfigures, where each panel is a different size, and in order for the figure elements to match size and style, I am using svgs

Comment: you are scaling anyway, so scaled pdf would have same size and alignment, but if you do want svg try `inkscapelatex=false` so the text stays with the svg (but all the svg package is doing is get inkskape to convert svg to pdf so pdftex can include it, so getting pdf from matlab is a lot simpler

Comment: I think we must be misunderstanding each other.

PDF code: https://pastebin.com/CwR9Yxqj
Screenshot of LaTeX output: https://imgur.com/a/Mt7f8wN

The fonts are not the same in the two sub-panels.

Comment: I'm afraid LaTeX can't do anything about this in general. Matlab exports the text objects left-aligned, so that's how they are rendered by LaTeX in the end. Don't know if you can change that in Matlab.

Comment: Thanks @schtandard!